# Suggested functions illegible

Tags: user-interface

I recently updated to Mathematica 11 and now the box which suggests what function you might be typing is completely illegible:

[image]

Is there any way to change the text / background color in this box or make it go away entirely?

Comment: Are you using the "ReverseColor" style sheet?  Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 11.1.1.0. How do you see / change what style sheet you are using?

Comment: If you haven't changed the style sheet, then it should be default.  I just thought, since it was dark, that you had changed it via the menu: `Format -> Stylesheet -> ReverseColor`.  Since you didn't do that, then you are just using the default.  What you're describing sounds like a bug, and I would consult tech support https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 3):

These are OpenGL issues (apparently affecting OSX in addition to Linux), either caused by a bad graphics driver or lack of memory.  If it always happens, it's unlikely to be the latter.  Try installing any available software updates.  If that doesn't help, send in a report to support and include a notebook with the result of evaluating SystemInformation[].

In order to turn off the the suggestions completely, open the Options Inspector (Ctrl-Shift-O), set the scope of Global Preferences, and search for ShowCodeAssist.  Unchecking the True/False box toggles it on and off.

Comment: It's on a macbook from 2014

Comment: Interesting.  I'll ask our Mac person if he's encountered this.  My answer about how to turn them off is the same, except it's Cmd-Shift-O to open the inspector.